# I am struggling with my python temperature unit converter

Tags: python

For a challenge I am tasked with creating a unit converter that can change the units. I chose degrees Celsius to Fahrenheit. I am quite new to Python. My problem is that I ask a question on the code e.g.

```
print("Enter Value: ")
```

How do I make it so that the value that a user enters becomes the variable `f` for Fahrenheit which can then be changed to Celsius so I can do this..

```
print((f - 32) / 1.8)
```

Can anyone  help and explain it in a way a beginner can understand?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Python3, what you need is:

```
temp=input("Temperature please?")
print((int(temp)-32)/1.8)
```

Also, please look up the docs Jacek linked to so that you understand what's really going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Use input() function:
[Input and Output Docs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output)

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = 0

# while loop
# wait until user set a input
while not temp:
  # default type in input is "str"
  user_input = input("Enter Value: ")
  if user_input.isdigit():
    temp = user_input

# we know every char is digit 
print (((int(temp)-32)/1.8))
```

Comment: I am using Python 3 and the raw_input does not work.

Comment: @HomeWork, sure is edited

Comment: Why are you doing an `any` check? Just `if not temp.isdigit()` is fine. Plus instead of raising an exception it would be better to just re-prompt the user.